# Form action didn't rest after downloading file with servlets in GWT?

Tags: java, servlets, gwt, download

I developed a small application in GWT to upload and download file after making some operations and it's working fine, but loading dialog image never stop after file downloaded, please advice.

client side code

```
public class Firstmodule implements EntryPoint
{


public void onModuleLoad()
{

    final PopupPanel popup = new PopupPanel(false, true); // Create a modal dialog box that will not auto-hide


    final FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
    final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
    VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    Image img = new Image("download.png");
    vPanel.add(img);

    form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
    // The HTTP request is encoded in multipart format.
    form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART); 

    form.setTitle("Family_Common_Fet");
    form.setAction(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "FileUploadGreeting"); 
    form.setWidget(vPanel);

    fileUpload.setName("uploader"); 
    vPanel.add(fileUpload);
    vPanel.setSpacing(20);
    Label maxUpload = new Label();
    maxUpload.setText("Text input file header: Datasheet, Vendor Code");
    vPanel.add(maxUpload);


    final Button submit = new Button("Upload and Run");
    vPanel.add(submit);
    submit.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
        {
            String filename = fileUpload.getFilename();
            if(!filename.endsWith(".txt"))
            {
                System.out.println(filename);
                Window.alert("only *.txt files accepted");
                return;
            }
            else if(filename.length() == 0)
            {
                Window.alert("Please Select Text File");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
// loading dialog image
                popup.add(new Image("loading_animation1.gif"));
                popup.setGlassEnabled(true); // Enable the glass panel
                popup.center(); // Center the popup and make it visible

                submit.setEnabled(false);
                submit.setFocus(true);
                form.submit();
            }

        }
    });

    // Add an event handler to the form.
    form.addSubmitHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitHandler() {
        public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event)
        {
            // This event is fired just before the form is submitted. We can take
            // this opportunity to perform validation.

        }
    });
    form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
        public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event)
        {

//trying to stop the loading dialodg
            popup.setGlassEnabled(false);

            submit.setEnabled(true);

            form.reset();
        }
    });

    DecoratorPanel decPanel = new DecoratorPanel();
    decPanel.setWidget(form);

    RootPanel.get("uploadContainer").add(decPanel);

}
```

servlet code

```
public class UploadFileHandler extends HttpServlet
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{

    System.out.println("Inside doPost");

    // Create a factory for disk-based file items
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    // Create a new file upload handler
    ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    // sizeMax - The maximum allowed size, in bytes. The default value of -1 indicates, that there is no limit.
    // 1048576 bytes = 1024 Kilobytes = 1 x 10 Megabyte
    fileUpload.setSizeMax(10485760);
    System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());

    if(!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
    {
        try
        {

            throw new FileUploadException("error multipart request not found");
        }catch(FileUploadException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try
    {

        List<FileItem> items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);

        if(items == null)
        {
            response.getWriter().write("File not correctly uploaded");
            return;
        }

        Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();

        String absofilepath = null;
        String fileName = null;
        String filepath = "temp//fileOutput_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt";
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////

            // if (item.isFormField()) {
            fileName = item.getName();
            System.out.println("fileName is : " + fileName);
            String typeMime = item.getContentType();
            System.out.println("typeMime is : " + typeMime);
            int sizeInBytes = (int) item.getSize();
            System.out.println("Size in bytes is : " + sizeInBytes);
            // byte[] file = item.get();

            absofilepath = getServletContext().getRealPath(filepath);
            item.write(new File(absofilepath));
            // }

        }

        String request_ip = getClientIpAddr(request);
        System.out.println("Request IP:" + request_ip);

        String tempoutFile = "output//" + fileName + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt";
        String absooutFile = getServletContext().getRealPath(tempoutFile);
        System.out.println("ouput file : " + absooutFile);
//************ some other operations in code*******///


}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
out.println("an Error has occuredin Exporter.bat" + e);
out.flush();
out.close();
}


        // ****************************Downlaod **********************************//
downloadFile(request, response, absooutFile);

 /*when i sing hashed code below it's return error in console and didn't stop the loading dialog image */
//            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
//            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html"); 
//            out.println("Check output File");
//            System.out.println("Upload Ok");
//             out.flush(); 
//             out.close();


    }catch(SizeLimitExceededException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File size exceeds the limit : 10 MB!!");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        out.println("Maximum file size should not exceed 10MB!!");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        out.println("an Error has occured");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

}

public static String getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
    if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
        ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
    }
    if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
        ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
    }
    if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
        ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
    }
    if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
        ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
    }
    if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
        ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
    return ip;
}

private void downloadFile(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, String filePath)
{
    try
    {
        File f = new File(filePath);
        int length = 0;
        ServletOutputStream op = resp.getOutputStream();
        ServletContext context = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
        String mimetype = context.getMimeType(filePath);

        resp.setContentType((mimetype != null) ? mimetype : "application/octet-stream");
        resp.setContentLength((int) f.length());
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Fam_Com_Fet.txt");

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        byte[] bbuf = new byte[in.available()];

        while((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1))
        {
            op.write(bbuf, 0, length);
        }

        in.close();
        op.flush();
        op.close();

        // f.delete();


    }catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    doPost(request, response);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SubmitCompleteHandler` is only guaranteed to be called when the server sends back HTML, (see javadoc) it won't work for an arbitrary file download.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mr Thomas Broyer Said, and i will but the right code for illustrating it as I got it.

at the beginning when I used the below code at my servlet in server side the response coming back to the client so there is nothing in client side will be executed again as it's already request coming back(lost the request).

```
    // ****************************Downlaod **********************************//
             downloadFile(request, response, absooutFile);
```

so the right way by using technique allow to firing download file action from client side to keep the (request , response)  activated so it will be able to complete my actions code

so client side code will be like this

```
public class MainGUI extends VerticalPanel implements ClickHandler,     SubmitCompleteHandler
{
private FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
private HTML descriptionLbl = new HTML("Please browse a text <B>[*.txt]</B>     file with header : Datasheet , Vendor code ");
private HorizontalPanel hPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
private FileUpload fileUploader = new FileUpload();
private Button validateBtn = new Button("Import and download");
private Label errorLbl = new Label("Error message will be here");
private Image img = new Image("download.png");
private MyDialog loadingDialog;


private LoadingDialog ldialog;
public MainGUI()
{
    setSpacing(5);
    hPanel.setSpacing(5);
    errorLbl.setStyleName("error");

    form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
    form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    form.setTitle("Fam_Com_Fet");
    form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(this);

    validateBtn.addClickHandler(this);

    fileUploader.setName("uploader");

    hPanel.add(fileUploader);
    add(img);
    setSpacing(20);
    add(hPanel);
    add(validateBtn);
    add(errorLbl);
    add(descriptionLbl);
    form.add(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
{

    exportcommonfeature();




}

private void exportcommonfeature()
{
    errorLbl.setText("");
    String fileName = fileUploader.getFilename();
    if(fileName == null || fileName.isEmpty())
    {
        errorLbl.setText("No File Specified");
        return;
    }
    if(!fileName.endsWith(".txt"))
    {
        errorLbl.setText("only *.txt files accepted");
        return;
    }



    ldialog = new LoadingDialog();


    // send the input to the server.

    form.setAction(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "UploadFileHandler");
    form.submit();
}

@Override
public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event)
{
    form.reset();

    if("Error".equalsIgnoreCase(getPlainTextResult(event)))
    {
        errorLbl.setText("Error occured while exporting");
    }else
    {
```

/********************* the download request will firing here *********************/

```
        form.setAction(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "UploadFileHandler?command=download&filepath="+getPlainTextResult(event));
        form.submit();
    }
```

UploadFileHandler: is mapping URL for my servlet name

download : is method in UploadFileHandler servlet to download the file

```
    ldialog.hide();


}

private String getPlainTextResult(SubmitCompleteEvent event)
{
    HTML html = new HTML(event.getResults());
    System.out.println("MainGUI File Path: " + html.getText());
    return html.getText();

}

public FormPanel getFormPanel()
{
    return this.form;
}

}
```

and the servlet code

```
public class UploadFileHandler extends HttpServlet
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{

    String filePath = request.getParameter("filepath");
    String commandName = request.getParameter("command");

    if("download".equalsIgnoreCase(commandName))
    {
        downloadFile(request, response, filePath);
    }
    else
        generateResultFile(request, response);

}


public void generateResultFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    System.out.println("Inside doPost");

    // Create a factory for disk-based file items
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    // Create a new file upload handler
    ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    // sizeMax - The maximum allowed size, in bytes. The default value of -1 indicates, that there is no limit.
    // 1048576 bytes = 1024 Kilobytes = 1 x 10 Megabyte
    fileUpload.setSizeMax(10485760);
    System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());

    if(!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
    {
        try
        {

            throw new FileUploadException("error multipart request not found");
        }catch(FileUploadException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try
    {

        List<FileItem> items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);

        if(items == null)
        {
            response.getWriter().write("File not correctly uploaded");
            return;
        }

        Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();

        String absofilepath = null;
        String fileName = null;
        String filepath = "temp//usrinpute_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt";
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////

            // if (item.isFormField()) {
            fileName = item.getName();
            System.out.println("fileName is : " + fileName);
            String typeMime = item.getContentType();
            System.out.println("typeMime is : " + typeMime);
            int sizeInBytes = (int) item.getSize();
            System.out.println("Size in bytes is : " + sizeInBytes);
            // byte[] file = item.get();

            absofilepath = getServletContext().getRealPath(filepath);
            item.write(new File(absofilepath));
            // }

        }

        String request_ip = getClientIpAddr(request);
        System.out.println("Request IP:" + request_ip);

        String tempoutFile = "output//" + fileName + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt";
        String absooutFile = getServletContext().getRealPath(tempoutFile);
        System.out.println("ouput file : " + absooutFile);
        // **************************************************************************************//



 response.getWriter().write(absooutFile);

        // ****************************End Loader**********************************//
//downloadFile(request, response, absooutFile);





    }catch(SizeLimitExceededException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File size exceeds the limit : 10 MB!!");
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try
        {
            out = response.getWriter();
        }catch(IOException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        out.println("Maximum file size should not exceed 10MB!!");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        try
        {
            response.getWriter().write("Error");
        }catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            response.getWriter().write("Error");
        }catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }



public static String getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
    if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
        ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
    }
    if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
        ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
    }
    if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
        ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
    }
    if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
        ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
    }
    if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
        ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
    return ip;
}

private void downloadFile(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, String filePath)
{
    try
    {
        File f = new File(filePath);
        int length = 0;
        ServletOutputStream op = resp.getOutputStream();
        ServletContext context = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
        String mimetype = context.getMimeType(filePath);

        resp.setContentType((mimetype != null) ? mimetype : "text/plain");
        resp.setContentLength((int) f.length());
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Family_Common_Features.txt");

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        byte[] bbuf = new byte[in.available()];

        while((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1))
        {
            op.write(bbuf, 0, length);
        }

        in.close();
        op.flush();
        op.close();

        // f.delete();


    }catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

on module load class

```
    public class Firstmodule implements EntryPoint
{
private MainGUI famLayout = new MainGUI();

public void onModuleLoad()
{

    loadingGUI();

}

/**
 * The message displayed to the user when the server cannot be reached or returns an error.
 */
static final String SERVER_ERROR = "An error occurred while " + "attempting to contact the server. Please check your network " + "connection and try again.";


private void loadingGUI()
{
    VerticalPanel Layout = new VerticalPanel();
    Layout.add(famLayout.getFormPanel());
    Layout.setSpacing(30);
    DecoratorPanel decPanel = new DecoratorPanel();
    decPanel.setWidget(Layout);
    decPanel.setWidth("60%");
    decPanel.setHeight("90%");
    RootPanel.get("uploadContainer").add(decPanel);
}
}
```

loading dialog class for testing the response will continue

```
    public class LoadingDialog extends PopupPanel
{

public LoadingDialog(){

    setGlassEnabled(true);
    setWidget(new Image("loading_animation1.gif"));
    center();
}

}
```

also here is the servlet mapping

```
    <servlet>
   <servlet-name>UploadFileHandler</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>edu.file.upload.com.server.UploadFileHandler</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>UploadFileHandler</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/FileUploadGreeting</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Edit @21-12-2016
simply you can download your file at server side and onSuccess
use this form panel

```
       FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
         form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
                            form.setAction(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() +    "ServletMappedName?command=download&filePath=" + filePath);
                            RootPanel.get().add(form);
                            form.submit();
```